# Liferay openam configuration using Ldap

Tags: liferay, openam

I want to configure liferay with openam.
I am able to login in liferay by ldap users but when i try to login via openam than in openam 
it will not allow to create user in it. 
And also want to know how to use ldap users in openam.

I want to login in liferay via openam by ldap users.
So please help  me to configure step by step liferay+openam+ldap configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the user in the LDAP Directory server configured as  data store in OpenAM (but you you not use OpenAM as provisioning tool).

Afterwards you have to configure OpenSSO auth plugnin in Liferay.

If Liferay and OpenAM are not located in the same cookie domain, you have to use an OpenAM Policy Agent to get the SSO tracking cookie in the other domain.

If you use Liferay Enterprise edition you can also use SAMLv2 integration.

You may also read the OpenSSO tech overview to get some idea how things work.